# Encoding.GetEncoding(437).GetString() bug?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, character-encoding

I have following test program

```
char c = '§';
Debug.WriteLine("c: " + (int)c);

byte b = Encoding.GetEncoding(437).GetBytes("§")[0];
Debug.WriteLine("b: " + b);

char c1 = Encoding.GetEncoding(437).GetString(new byte[] { 21 })[0];
Debug.WriteLine("c1: " + (int)c1);
```

This produces following result:

```
c: 167
b: 21
c1: 21
```

As I can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) GetBytes is working correctly
167 in unicode => 21 in CP437
but GetString is not working
21 in CP437 => 21 in unicode

Is this a bug or my mistake?

Comment: A long shot, but do both `GetBytes` and `GetString` return arrays with just a single element?

Comment: This is probably because 167 cannot be written in CP437 so its mapped to placeholder 21 (maybe `?`) in CP437. the placeholder is mapped back to the placeholder in unicode which is 21 too.

Comment: @Dani: Are you sure?  That character does exist and is valid in CP437, which should use one byte to represent it.  It's probably more than one byte in Unicode, but not in 437.. Check the wiki linked for char 21, which is that character.

Comment: @Kieren Johnstone - Yes GetBytes(...).Length = 1 and GetString(...).Length = 1

Comment: Can you try displaying/printing the string returned from `GetString`, again out of interest?  I don't know the inner workings of these methods but I agree it seems very odd.

Comment: on my machine its &#21; (a square)

Comment: [Bonus Reading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57976504/12597)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CP437 is not "two-way" for characters in the range 0-31. As stated in the Wikipedia page you linked:

> For many uses, the codes in the range 0 to 31 and the code 127 will
>   not produce these symbols. Some (or all) of them will be interpreted
>   as ASCII control characters.

Mapping an Unicode character to a supported CP437 character that is in this range works, but not the other way around. For example, take characters represented by bytes 13 and 10: chances are that if you got them inside a CP437 string, you actually want carriage return and line feed characters to be preserved, and not converted to a bullet and a music note. This behavior is normal: it's not a bug.

Comment: Its what you could call a narrowing conversion

Comment: OMG, hate to be beaten by such MS design decisions. Now I need to find/write two-way CP437 encoding. :-(

Comment: @SeeR: The WinAPI function [**MultiByteToWideChar**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar) supports this through it's `MB_USEGLYPHCHARS` flag: *"Use glyph characters instead of control characters."*.  But be warned that if your text had `CRLF`, they will come back as "♪◙" - because your file no longer has any `CR`+`LF`, but instead has `Eighth Note`+`Inverse White Circle`

Answer (score 0):

.net supports two different characters, both of which are (usually) rendered as `§`:

```
char c1 = (char)21;
char c2 = (char)167;

Console.WriteLine(c1 == c2);  // prints false
Console.WriteLine(c1);        // prints §
Console.WriteLine(c2);        // prints §
```

Character 21 is a special control character, which is rendered as `§` when output in text mode.

[CP437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) allows for 21 to be interpreted as either a control character or as the literal `§`. Apparently, `GetString` chooses to interpret it as the control character (which is a perfectly valid option), and, thus, maps it to the Unicode control character 21 rather than to the Unicode literal `§`.

Comment: In my machine `Console.WriteLine(c1)` prints `EMPTY` and `Console.WriteLine(c2);` prints `§`

Comment: I think so, I am using windows xp sp3 and Visual Studio 2010.