# How to convert characters from code page 437?

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, character-encoding

I'm trying to convert text that is encoded in [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437#Characters):

```
☺☻♥♦♣♠•◘○♂♀♪♫☼►◄↕‼¶§▬↨↑↓→←∟↔▲▼
```

These are all real, valid, Unicode characters - you could represent them in a C# string just fine:

```
String original = "☺☻♥♦♣♠•◘○♂♀♪♫☼►◄↕‼¶§▬↨↑↓→←∟↔▲▼";
Console.WriteLine("Original: "+original);

>Original: ☺☻♥♦♣♠•◘○♂♀♪♫☼►◄↕‼¶§▬↨↑↓→←∟↔▲▼
```

And if you get the unicode code points they correspond to, you see they are indeed all valid unicode characters:

```
Console.WriteLine("Original code points: "+StringToCodePoints(original));

>Original code points:  U+263A U+263B U+2665 U+2666 U+2663 U+2660 U+2022 U+25D8 U+25CB U+2642 U+2640 U+266A U+266B U+263C U+25BA U+25C4 U+2195 U+203C U+00B6 U+00A7 U+25AC U+21A8 U+2191 U+2193 U+2192 U+2190 U+221F U+2194 U+25B2 U+25BC
```

### Encode into code page 437

And if you have C# convert them to code page 437, you get an array of expected bytes:

```
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(437);
Byte[] data = enc.GetBytes(original);
Console.WriteLine("CP 437: "+BitConverter.ToString(data));

>CP 437: 01-02-03-04-05-06-07-08-09-0B-0C-0D-0E-0F-10-11-12-13-14-15-16-17-18-19-1A-1B-1C-1D-1E-1F
```

Which is exactly what i expect; i am testing with the first 30 characters of the 437 code page:

[image]

### Convert back from code page 437

Now i try to convert those CP437 encoded bytes back to characters, and i get non-sense garbage:

```
String actual = enc.GetString(data);
Console.WriteLine("Actual: "+actual);

>Actual:
```

And looking at the actual **Char**s in the string, i get:

```
Console.WriteLine("Actual code points: "+StringToCodePoints(actual));

>Actual code points:  U+0001 U+0002 U+0003 U+0004 U+0005 U+0006 U+0007 U+0008 U+0009 U+000B U+000C U+000D U+000E U+000F U+0010 U+0011 U+0012 U+0013 U+0014 U+0015 U+0016 U+0017 U+0018 U+0019 U+001A U+001B U+001C U+001D U+001E U+001F
```

So .NET did everything completely wrong.

How do i make it do it right?

[CS Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4GHeip)

### Answer

The problem is that Code Page 437 has a quirk where the first 20 values can each repreesnt two different characters

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 |
☺  ☻  ♥  ♦  ♣  ♠  •  ◘  ○  ♂  ♀  ♪  ♫  ☼  ►  ◄  ↕  ‼  ¶  §  ▬  ↨  ↑  ↓  →  ←  ∟  ↔  ▲  ▼  |
␁  ␂  ␃  ␄  ␅  ␆  ␇  ␈  ␉  ␊  ␋  ␌  ␍  ␎  ␏  ␐  ␑  ␒  ␓  ␔  ␕
```

␖  ␗  ␘  ␙  ␚  ␛  ␜  ␝  ␞  ␟

And so given a byte sequence, e.g.

- `0D 0A`

you have no idea if that is meant to represent:

- **`CR` `LF`**

or

- **`♪` `◙`**

So code page 437 (and code 850 which uses 437 for the first 128) are just bad code pages. And anyone who uses them is just wrong.

Comment: FWIW, .NET appears to follow the [Unicode definition](https://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/PC/CP437.TXT) of CP437, which excludes the "screen code" glyphs from the mapping. Don't forget this affects 0x7f (Delete) as well as 0x00-1f.